# Using separated columns for a table_array in Vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I was wondering if it was possible to use separated columns for my table_array value in Vlookup.  For instance:  I have a list of names in column A and a list of results in column C. In column D I have the formula: =VLOOKUP(B1,table_array,2) where I want the table array to contain columns A & C and return the value of Column C.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: why `=VLOOKUP(B1,A:C,3,0)` doesn't suit?

Comment: `I have a list of names in column A and a list of results in column C` - as per my understanding it should be `A:C,3`

Comment: Thank you all for the help, I was overthinking the problem and should have realized I could use the extra columns in my table array.  In my mind, since they were not useful to what I was trying to accomplish I naturally tried to ignore them completely. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
=VLOOKUP(B1, A1:C6, 3, FALSE)
```

[image]